# list.files() doesn't find all the files in a folder

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to load some ".xls" into R. the folder contains 8 .XLS files and 8 .csv files which I made by manually opening up the .xls files and saving as a .csv. I realised that I could use `read.xls()` from the `gdata` package to load the .xls files directly which is helpful as the data is received in .xls format. however when I use `list.files()` in the 3 newest .xls files are missed off the list. Their associated .csv's are however included. if I open the files and convert them to .xls then run `list.files()` again they show up, if I rename them in the Explorer they will not show up when I run `list.files` again. The Excel files may come from a different region's version of Excel as they come from an office in a different country, but I wouldn't have thought that would have an effect.

The files were emailed to me and so as an experiment I created a new folder and saved the files from Outlook to the new folder, the result when I ran `list.files()` was the same, also when I converted them.

```
list.files(getwd())
```

returns

```
character(0)
```

It makes no difference if I use `list.files( getwd() )` or specify the file extension.

I would like to know what I am missing so i can avoid having to open each file individually or risk missing files when I run my script.

Apologies for this question not being reproducible.

**EDIT**

At the suggestion of Jbaum the following code was run and results were returned

```
shell(sprintf('dir /b %s', normalizePath(getwd())), intern=TRUE)
[1] "'\\\\\\ **File path**'"
[2] "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory."                             
[3] "UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory."                                
[4] "The system cannot find the file specified."
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warning message:
running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c dir /b \\\\ **File path**' had status 1
```

Note: I have replaced the file path with **File path**, and have doubled the number of backslashes so they display as in R

Comment: Did you `setwd` correctly? Does `getwd` return the expected path?

Comment: Yes getwd returns the expected path. It's important to remember that files.list returns **some** but not all of the files, and when the files are converted they get listed, this wouldn't happen if the path was incorrect.

Comment: What's the result of `list.files(all.files=TRUE)`?

Comment: That returns the same but with the addition of "." and ".."

Comment: How about `system(sprintf('ls %s', getwd()), intern=TRUE)`? (After ensuring `getwd()` returns the path containing the files of interest.)

Comment: Running that code returns the following error
"Error in system(sprintf("ls %s", getwd()), intern = TRUE) : 
  'ls' not found"

Comment: Apologies... perhaps try `shell(sprintf('dir /b %s', normalizePath(getwd())), intern=TRUE)`.

Comment: If your working directory path contains spaces, you'll need to wrap `%s` in quotes, thus: `shell(sprintf('dir /b "%s"', normalizePath(getwd())), intern=TRUE)`. Do the files show if you navigate to the path in a Windows Command Prompt window and then enter `dir`? This is essentially what I'm attempting to do with the above `shell` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was to do with network syncing of a corporate PC and not actually to do with R.**

The system that I am using syncs all files from the C drive of the PC the to the  network drive, the default setting for all programs is to look at the files on the network drive when the PC is connected to the network.

However when I transferred the files from outlook they were stored on the local instance of the folder and no the networked one, making them invisible to R which viewed the network instance.

When I converted the files using Excel the new files were by default saved to the network allowing them to be seen by R. when the system went through the synchronisation process all files were finally accessible by R.

A way to avoid this problem in future is to do a manual sync if the files are not visible to check this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had 20 files named: *file_1, file_2,...file_20*.

```
list.files(".", pattern, recursive=T, full.names=T, all.files=T)
```

didn't list all 20 files, it was missing some of the files.

I tried to use regular expression and all the files got listed, here is how I did:

```
list.files(".", "file_+[0-9]", recursive=T, full.names=T, all.files=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with RStudio on my mac. Only some files from the directory were being listed. Turned out if files are stored in iCloud and not downloaded locally, R saw the file as `filename.csv.icloud` and skipped it.