# R list.files not showing all files (pathing issue maybe?)

Tags: r

I am trying to make a list of files using list.files (Code below):

```
 raw.file.list <-"/Volumes/TempData/Heather Speckman/EC_Restored/NNTR EC/2014/Unpacked Data"
 setwd(raw.file.list)    
 raw.file.list <- list.files(path = raw.data.dir, recursive = T, full.names = T)
```

I know that there are 4,000+ files in this raw.data.dir, this command is only listing the 1,200 of them-- and it's 1,200 I do **NOT** see when I look in Windows.

Can anyone help me out as to why?

Additional info:

The file path (raw.file.list) does exist, R moves there just fine.  The pathway is correct and identical when I look in Windows and R (besides / and \ ).  I also tried this on my Mac, and got the same non-functional result.

```
 raw.file.list <-"/Volumes/TempData/Heather Speckman/EC_Restored/NNTR EC/2014/Unpacked Data"
```

is a work server which works just like a hard drive.  It has never given me trouble before.  If I copy/paste the data to:

```
 raw.file.list <-"/Volumes/TempData/Heather Speckman/EC_Restored/NNTR EC/2014/Test Folder"
```

it works just fine.  For work flow reasons, I don't want copy/paste to be the solution here.

If I try:

```
 file.name = "Example_file_name.csv"; file.exists(file.name)
```

R says false.  My computer sees the file and opens it just fine.

Trying:

```
 setwd(raw.data.dir); list.files(path = ".", recursive = T, full.names = T)
```

Gives only the 1200 files, not the full 4,000.  Same if I try
     dir()

Comment: anything weird in your setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765164/list-files-doesnt-find-all-the-files-in-a-folder

Comment: No.  I did go through that post and it's suggestions before posting this question.

Comment: have you found an example of file that isn't showing up and tried `file.exists` on it ?

Comment: Yes. R says the file doesn't exist and won't open the csv.  Windows says it does exist and easily opens it.

Comment: What is the value of `raw.data.dir`?

Comment: A really long pathway.  It does exist, and setwd(raw.data.dir) does work.

Comment: Put it in your question.

Comment: Is `raw.data.dir` a relative or absolute path? Are the 1200 listed files really located in your expected directory? What does `setwd(raw.data.dir); list.files(path = ".", recursive = T, full.names = T)` give you?

Comment: Updated the post to include more info and address comments

Comment: Are you sure that all the folders and files have the correct permissions? At the command line you could preface the command with sudo and see if you get different results.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error: file path malfunction.